# Returning a reference to a mapped value that is not a pointers

Tags: c++, dictionary, stl

I think it'll be better if I show my code first, then explain my problem.

```
std::map<std::string, SManager> m_managers;

//SResourceManager is derived from SManager
SResourceManager& getResourceManager() { return m_managers["resource_manager"]->second; }
```

What I'm trying to do is return a reference from a SManager (which would be the copy of SResourceManager) to be able to use elsewhere. I know I can use things like std::shared_ptr, but I'd prefer not to use pointers in this situation because I want the SResourceManager within the map to possibly change, but stay in there. Is there a way to cast this to a value that I can actually return?

Thanks

Comment: Why does `second` return a pointer? It isn't obvious unless you show `SManager`.

Comment: Sorry, I misspoke. I'll edit the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"SResourceManager is derived from SManager". Going from a base type to a derived type will require an explicit cast.

However, you have a bigger problem. Your map contains SManager objects directly. As a consequence it does not and can never contain SResourceManager objects or any other derived type. Whatever code you've written to populate that map is most likely ending up slicing off the derived portions.

If you want to have things in terms of a base type that could actually refer to objects of derived types then you need to use pointers in some manner. unique_ptr or shared_ptr are reasonable options.

So you might end up with something like:

```
std::map<std::string, std::unique_ptr<SManager>> m_managers;

SResourceManager& getResourceManager() { return *static_cast<SResourceManager*>(m_managers["resource_manager"].get()); }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using incorrect syntax. If to suppose that type SManager is declared as pointer to a polymorphic class then the function will look the following way

```
SResourceManager& getResourceManager() { return *m_managers["resource_manager"]; }
```